# Cannot mount HFS+ drive on Mac 10.14

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, mount

I have an external drive in HFS+ format. However, the disk could not be mounted (i.e. not shown up in Finder) to my Mac (v10.14). Here are the `diskutil` result and what I tried.

```
> diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         500.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +500.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            477.1 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 44.3 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                509.8 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      4.3 GB     disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        +24.3 MB    disk2
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         32.3 KB    disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Flash Player            24.2 MB    disk2s2

/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk3
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS My_Drive                999.8 GB   disk3s2
```

I tried `sudo diskutil mount /dev/disk3s2` and got `Volume on disk3s2 timed out waiting to mount`. Does anyone know what happened and/or how I could get it fixed?

Comment: Did you try using Disk Utility to do a First Aid scan on both your disk itself (to check the GPT) as well as the HFS+ partition?

Answer (score 0):

Is your unmounted drive listed in Disk Utility as greyed out? If yes, then select the drive and press the Mount button. If this doesn't work then try a different cable connection or plug it to another Mac system.